# Python delete from date column row contains string

Tags: python, rows

I have joined two dataframes: one containing annual date and another created using date range for monthly date.
After joining two dataframes, there are some duplicate date values for which I assigned suffix '_dup'.
Now, how do I drop the rows containing '_dup' values. My dataframe is as below:

[image]

Now, I used following code to remove/drop the date row containing '_dup'

```
for i in range (117):
if df5.iloc[i,0].str.contains ('_dup'):
    del df5.loc[i,0]
```

I get error :

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-171-ae80d413249e> in <module>()
      1 for i in range (117):
----> 2     if df5.iloc[i,0].str.contains ('_dup'):
      3         del df5.loc[i,0]

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'
```

I also tried the code:

```
df5[~df5.index.str.contains("_dup")]
```

It is giving error that:

```
AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values (i.e. inferred_type is 'string', 'unicode' or 'mixed')`
```

Comment: Why don't you just use [`drop_duplicates()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) instead of using a suffix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that `df5.iloc[i,0]` accesses a single `str` datapoint in the column, so you cannot apply the `str` function to it again. You can apply the `str.contains` function to the whole column at once like so:

```
df = df.loc[~df["col_name"].str.contains("dup")]
```

However the `str.contains` function won't work if there are mixed datatypes in the column. In that case you would need to convert the type first (`df["col_name"] = df["col_name"].astype(str)`). Or if your duplicate values were the only datapoints with string type you can just filter out based on type like so:

```
df.loc[~df["col_name"].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, str))]
```